# if/else statement with arrays is failing

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

So the code is really simple, its just a main(), but there is something wrong in the **if/else statement** in the **while cycle** and I dont't know what it is, I thought this is how it supposed to work, but clearly its not.

The code is creating a **11-element array**, but the 0th element of the array is typed in by the user. So for example I type in 5, the array have the numbers from 5 to 15. Then the program shows you the numbers in the array. Then you can type in any numbers, and if your number is **equal to any of the numbers in the array**, then the program should say: "YEES!!!".

**The problem is**, the program always says, what it should only if the input number is not equal to any number in the array...

So can please someone explain me why the if/else statement is failing?

*I also wrote this in Code::Blocks if that changes something...*

**The code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numbers[11];
    int input;

    cout << "Type in a number: ";
    cin >> input;

    for (int i=0; i<11; i++){
        numbers[i] = input +i;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<11; i++){
        cout << numbers[i] <<endl;
    }

    while (true){
        cout<<endl;
        cout << "Type in a number:" <<endl;
        cin.sync();
        cin >> input;
        if (input <= numbers[11] && input >= numbers[0])
            cout << "YEES!!!" << endl;
        else{
            cout << "Number is out of range!" <<endl;
            cout << "Please try again!" <<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please improve your title. Knowing that you wrote your code for fun helps nobody who wonders whether they might be experts on the problem you're having. Describe the actual problem! Also, you're way to prone to saying "I think it's this and that"; we don't know why you would think that, and something seems to be wrong. So, clearly explain your assumptions. Explain what you've done to test whether they are true!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the feedback, this was my first question, but i changed the question, and the details, so now i hope its more helpful for anyone who want to help... Is there still something that i should improve?

Comment: I like it like this! There's certainly always a bit room to improve, but you really got an answer when people started reading your question, so I'd say this was a full success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing starts with zero, so if you create an array with a size of N last index always will be N-1. In your case, the index of the last element is 10.

```
if (input <= numbers[10] && input >= numbers[0]) // accurate
```

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem, sometimes i forget basic things like this...

Answer (score 1):

The last element in your array should be 10, not 11 because you start at zero. Try doing

```
if (input <= numbers[10] && input >= numbers[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers clearly handle the indexing issue (array indexes start at `0` and the last index of an 11 element array is `10`) there is a little bit of an XY problem happening here.
If you need to determine if an input number is within the range from 1 to 11, there is absolutely no need to use an array at all. You simply need to check that it's less than or equal to 11 and greater than or equal to 1.

```
if (input <= 11 && input >= 1) {
    // ...
}
```

Your code is essentially trying to do this but storing the bottom of the range in `numbers[0]` and the top of the range in `numbers[10]` with the rest of the array being unused. If you want you could use two variables to store these limits.

Comment: That's true, that would be a good optimization, thanks!